# Subgraph of paths of a graph has cycles?

Tags: graphs

Suppose that we have multiple minimum paths from $u$ to $v$ of a graph $G=(V,E)$. Now, we take this paths and create a subgraph $G'=(V',E')$ where for each $v \in V$ and $e \in E$ we have that $v \in V'$ and $e \in E'$ if and only if $v$ and $e$ exists in one of the minimum paths.

Now, my question is:

- It is possible that $G'$ has cycles?
- There is a way to prove this?

**Edit 1:** I forgot to put here that $G$ is an weighted directed graph. Yuval made clear that for undirected graphs we can have cycles, as we can just take an graph like $C_{4}$. But I am more interested in undirected graphs. We can consider that these minimum paths are the $k$ shortest paths in $G$, with $k>0$.

**Edit 2:** For each $e \in E$ we have a weight function $f(e) = w$, where $w$ is the weight of the edge. This weight is non-negative and can not be zero.

Comment: Take a square (i.e., $C_4$), and let $u,v$ be opposite vertices.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But this will only be true for undirected graphs, right? This behavior can be replicated in directed graphs?

Comment: Take a $C_4$, make all arcs point away from  $u$ and towards $v$, Yuval's opposite vertices.

Comment: I don't see how weights make any difference. Just assign the same weight to all edges.

Comment: Is it a weighted graph, i.e., weights on the edges?  Can the weights be zero?  Can they be negative?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It is going to make a difference because in a $C_{4}$ where all arcs point away from $u$ and towards $v$ and they are opposite vertexes, all minimum paths between $u$ and $v$ points towards $v$ only. That means that when we create the subgraph $G'$ from these paths, we never could have a back edge from any vertex. So, this would not form a cycle.

Comment: Some hints: First, prove that every vertex in $G'$ has a *uniquely determined* distance from $u$ (meaning that regardless of which path you take from $u$ to get to some vertex $x$, you travel the same distance).  Call the distance for $x$ $d(x)$.  Next, notice that for there to be a cycle in $G'$, it must contain some path $y \dots z$ such that $d(y) > d(z)$.  This path must itself contain some edge $y'z'$ such that $d(y') > d(z')$.